# How to store the first 256 ascii characters in an array?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I'm trying to store the first 256 ASCII characters in a string array.

I have something like this:

```
   string values[256];
   for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
        char temp = i;
        values[i] = temp;
   }
```

But I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this. The error i'm getting is:

```
   invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
```

Comment: nope, i'm using the g++ compiler in linux

Comment: Changing `string` to `char` will already work.

Comment: There are only 128 characters in the ASCII set.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code, as far as I can see. http://ideone.com/mLwYP

Comment: Change `=` to `+=` and it will work. But, did you want 256 strings?

Comment: ohh i think the issue was that i was doing the initialization and assignment in one line (i.e. invoking the copy constructor, rather than the assignment operator)

Comment: @user1202422, Yes, that makes sense, as the constructor doesn't take a char. Assignment does.

Comment: I have a feeling that `string` is being typedef'd into something else. OP, can you confirm?

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III I think what happened was that I was doing declaration and assignment both in one line, but in the code I wrote here, I split it up into multiple lines. when split, it works.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. You should probably edit your post then to reflect your original code.

Answer (score 4):

The soluiton is to do this:

```
#include <string>

std::string values[256];
for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
  char temp = i;
  values[i] = temp;
}
```

as can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/mLwYP), there is nothing wrong with this code. I am assuming that you have good reasons to keep an array of 256 single character `std::strings`.

`std::string` has an [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) that takes a single char as argument, so there is nothing wrong with the above code.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII he's pointing out that it should work, and it should :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner in c++11:

```
std::iota(std::begin(values), std::end(values), '\0');
```

iota is in `<algorithm>` header, begin and end are in `<iterator>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you declare an array of string data type like this it will create 256 different string, each string with an ability to store as many characters as they can be placed into the your computer's memory

and each variable like `values[i]` is a pointer to a string in the memory, That is the reason of error. char to char pointer

that's why we need to have single char array like `char values[256]` to make data types same on both sides.

but if you want to do it in same way you will need to convert the ascii value into string.

..............................................
a string is a combination of characters

Answer (score 0):

We have a standard ASCII character set from 0 to 127 and an extended ASCII which ranges 128 upto 255.

If you could state the purpose of storing the 256 characters in a string array, we could guide to a more appropriate STL or another solution.

If you really want to use it like an array why not simply use it like an array of chars or a std::vector of chars.

If you want to use std::string, try something like this:

```
   string str;
   str.reserve(256);
   str.clear();
   string::iterator iter;
   for(i=0;i<256;i++)
     iter=str.insert(str.begin()+i,i);
   //Do something with str here.
```